I hope that the SearchText textbox can display the value of SearchBox while inputting in SearchBox
I hope that the SearchText textbox can display the value of SearchBox while inputting in SearchBox. What is wrong with my program? Because it doesn't change the SearchText
code:
Option Compare Database
Private Sub SearchBox_Change()
Me.SearchText = Me.SearchBox.Text
Me.ListResults.Requery
End Sub
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
